# What's the effect of brewing with Lalemand Verdant over 23 C?

Tags: yeast

Lalemand seems to be producing a lot of nice esthers at 22-23 degrees. I was wondering what this looks like at 30~32 degrees. Would the esthers become off-flavours?

Comment: Try it, and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Yeast will probably produce a high amount of fusel alcohols (also called high alcohols) that may be considered off-flavours, beer will taste more alcoholic, these alcohols can also cause headaches.